# Do I have to change my source code to use xcache or other PHP opcode cacher?

Tags: php, optimization, apc, xcache

I would like to use a PHP opcode cache, like APC and XCache.

TO have benefit from this cachers, do I have to change something on my php code or just install one of them?

I have seen there are APIs, do I have to use them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The APIs are to exert manual control over how the caches work, but if they are properly installed and configured, they will "just work".

Answer (score 0):

About APC: you can just install APC and it will work.
If you want, you can adjust size of memory, allowed for APC.
And I recommend to set this setting:

```
apc.slam_defense = Off
```

Comment: Care to add some reasoning behind your recommendation?

Comment: as in the php documentation for apc mentioned this setting is deprecated and replaced by apc.write_lock [link](http://www.php.net/manual/de/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.slam-defense)

Comment: @Nev Stokes my experience. Without this setting PHP will generate warnings very often. On loaded site it will mean impossible to use APC to cache user's data.  I use last stable version of APC and I know, what about I'm talking.

Comment: @peaceman write_lock affects only opcode cache, when I'm talking about users cache.

Comment: Chill OZ_ I wasn't trying to diss your knowledge or anything. People are more likely to follow suggestions if you explain them. FWIW, I too use APC and have no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

As previous posters have mentioned, once properly installed, APC will "just work" by storing the compiled PHP code to save this having to be done each time. There is nothing else for you to do.

However, you can also leverage APC to store settings that you may have previously got from a database lookup for example. Take a look at [apc_store](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) and related functions.